# How to "save" a long query for reuse in a where clause? Is it even necessary?

Tags: sql, select, view, where-clause

I want to select some elements from `table1` using some data from `table2` and `table3` with conditions that depend on a processing-cost-intensive query in `table3` which I have to perform twice. The question is, how can I optimise this so I only have to perform the expensive query once? Specifically, my script looks like this:

```sql
select *
from table1
where table1.x in
 (select table2.x
 from table2
 where table2.y in
   (select table3.y
   from table3
   where --some complicated clause C)
 )
or table1.y in
 (select table3.y
 from table3
 where --the same complicated clause C as above)
```

The query with clause `C`,

```
 (select table3.y
 from table3
 where --the same complicated clause C as above)
```

appears twice and takes a very long time, so I would like to only do it once. How is this achievable? Do I need a view? I'm not familiar with views but *I am under the constraint that I can only run one script with one main instruction* (such as the main `select` select in the above script).

Or is it even necessary to worry about such an optimisation - will sql recognise that the query with clause `C` appears twice and will only do it once, in fact?

Comment: Details are up to the sql server you are using, but try googling "Common Table Expression" ...

Comment: Yes! Common table expressions are exactly what I needed. It was surprisingly hard (i.e. impossible, leading me to post this question) to find this on google without knowing the terminology...

Comment: Be a good sport and close the question, so it no longer draws attention

Comment: @user2722968 I don't have the close option, I think I don't have enough reputation.